# Issue teleporting a character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an issue, I programmed a simple code to teleport the main character of my game from A position to B. The code works, but when the character touches the collider and teleport to the new position, it goes a little bit further than the position I need it to be and the character animations and horizontal movement stop working.

The rigidbody, triggers of my controller, and general values of movement and physics doesn't change the only values that change are x transform position and y transform position:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision){
        if (collision.tag == "Transporter"){           
               transform.position = new Vector3(collision.transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 1, transform.position.z);
               rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please add more detail so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: ok, The character walks and touches a trigger collider of an object, then it goes to the position of the object that's it, transporter is a tag an object in game has, and is simple as that, i will edit the code tell me if i need more details

Comment: do you need the all controller code?

Comment: If your animations arent working sounds like an issue with how you are setting the animation triggers.

Comment: i also checked the triggers of the animation, i have a question, if the animation's triggers aren't properly working does the controller works or it doesn't? the triggers works normal, all them are set as public, and there is nothing wrong, and i also checked the animations triggers and bools, and they are working fine. Also the other thing i just notice is that the trigger "isGrounded" is checked but the Y transform axis isn't static, is randomly moving some units.